# Integer promotion in C program

Tags: c, integer-promotion

I have written a simple C program and wanted to know if integer promotion is happening in it.

> Please explain how integer promotion happens and how to avoid it?

```
/* start of main */

unsigned short int res;
unsigned short int bsp;
signed short int analog;

bsp = 2215;
analog = 2213;
if((signed short int)(bsp - analog) > 0){
    res = bsp - analog;
    printf("%d", res);
}
else{
    res = analog - bsp;
    printf("%d", res);
}
```

Comment: Hint: `printf("%d", res);`--> look there...

Comment: @Ravi for integer promotion see what Sourav said, however I have a doubt: instead of "integer promotion" did you mean "usual arithmetic conversion"?

Comment: `bsp - analog` and `analog - bsp` both cause promotion.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti `... Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. ...` (§6.3.1.8)

Comment: @Adriano Repetti.  You're splitting hairs unnecessarily.  The conversion from `signed` to `unsigned` is described - by the C standards - as an integral promotion.

Comment: @Adriano.  Read, for example, 1999 ISO C standard, Section 6.3.1.1.  (end of para 2).    "If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the integer promotions."

Comment: @Peter I see my previous comment sounds more rude than I expected, sorry for that. What I mean is: no, integer promotions imply no "conversion" and no possibly data loss. With a conversion you may (implementation defined) loose something. C standard (sorry I'm referring to C11, I can't check C99 now) they're described in separate places (and as separate things) because they happen in different places (with pretty different results). A promotion won't (probably) affect your code. A conversion may break it...

Comment: Integer promotion occurs with 1) `bsp - analog` twice,  2) `(signed short int)(...) > 0)` 3) `printf("%d", res);` twice 4) `analog - bsp`

Comment: "how to avoid it" --> use `int/unsigned` rather than `unsigned short int/signed short int`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to restrict this answer to an `int` being 32 bit, and `short` being 16 bit.

Then `bsp - analog` is an expression of type `int`.

The behaviour on casting this to a `short` is undefined if `bsp - analog` cannot be represented in a `short`. So write code like `(signed short int)(bsp -  analog)` with caution.

There's an implicit promotion of `res` to an `int` in your `printf` call.

Finally, the best way to avoid unwanted promotions is to work with the same type throughout. Consider using an `int` or a `long` in your case.

Comment: NMDV, but `Finally, to circumvent the otherwise implicit promotion of res to an int in your printf call, use %hu as the formatter.` is probably not the correct words to be used.

Comment: notice , "the argument will
have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall
be converted to short int or unsigned short int before printing);" so, you never stop the promotion, actually.

Comment: @Bathsheba Isn't _"implementation defined"_ instead of _"undefined behavior"_?

Answer (score 2):

The integer promotions are issued from two different sources in your program:

- *usual arithmetic conversions* (because of binary `-` operator<sup>1</sup>)
- *default argument promotions* (because of `printf` variadic function)

In both cases, either argument of type `signed short int` is promoted to `int`, assuming, that `int` range can hold every number that former type can hold. Normally, it happens this way as `short` and `int` are 16-bit and 32-bit wide respectively.

---

<sup>1) As a well as of `>` operator (as mentioned in chux's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243361/integer-promotion-in-c-program/38243674#comment63915761_38243674) below).</sup>

Comment: A _usual arithmetic conversion_ occurs because of the `>` compare also.